# How refrigerant releases heat to surroundings

Tags: thermodynamics

when boiling point of refrigerant is -40 degree celsius (R22) how it will becomes liquid and cools down when surrounding temperature is more than 25 degree.

in condenser it has high temp which transfer heat surroundings but refrigerant itself has boiling point of -40 Dg, why it will not remain vapour.

Answer (score 1):

> when boiling point of refrigerant is -40 degree celsius (R22) how it
>   will becomes liquid and cools down when surrounding temperature is
>   more than 25 degree.

Because if your values are correct for Freon (I haven't checked them) the boiling point of R22 (freon) is -40 C only at atmospheric pressure. In the condenser the pressure is much higher than atmospheric pressure and therefore its boiling/condensing point is then + 25 C.

A replacement for freon (due to environmental concerns) is HFC-134a. At 1 atmosphere in the evaporator its boiling point is about -25 C. In the condenser at around 6 atmospheres, its boiling point is about + 20 C.

Hope this helps.